# What is return type of read_frames() scikits audiolab?

Tags: python, scipy

In Scikits audiolab, I'm trying to split audio's two channels in two different file, and what I observed from read_frames method is some numbers that looks like list but not exactly. And the documentation does not explicitly mention its data type. So basically it looks like,

```
[[-0.25283813 -0.05990601]
 [-0.28274536 -0.06542969]
 [-0.30093384 -0.06890869]
 ..., 
 [ 0.21939087  0.36206055]
 [ 0.22756958  0.36981201]
 [ 0.22592163  0.37960815]]
```

What is return type of read_frames()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, even without the documentation you can always `print type(returned_value)` and discover that in this case it is a [`numpy.ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) instance. By the look of it, a two-dimensional one with lots of rows and two columns.

And the [documentation](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/sphinx/fullapi.html#scikits.audiolab.Sndfile.read_frames) *does* mention the type explicitly:

> Read the given number of frames and **put the data into a numpy array** of the requested dtype.